# hibernate.LazyInitializationException after restarting webapp

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have been using this third-party web app hosted on tomcat for a long time, I don't make any code changes to it. I recently restarted the web app and it is throwing this error:
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

I initially restarted the tomcat server to increase the -Xmx param, and then this issue happened, I don't think it has anything to do with this parameter, but I have reverted it and it still doesn't work.

This is the error log:

```
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:140)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.proxy.GroovyAwareJavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(GroovyAwareJavassistLazyInitializer.java:195)
        at cuanto.ProjectGroup_$$_javassist_1.getName(ProjectGroup_$$_javassist_1.java)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor310.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1602)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1099)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3311)
        at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1111)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetPropertySafe(AbstractCallSite.java:341)
        at cuanto.Project.toString(Project.groovy:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.format(InvokerHelper.java:550)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.formatList(InvokerHelper.java:602)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.format(InvokerHelper.java:527)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.format(InvokerHelper.java:504)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.toArrayString(InvokerHelper.java:689)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.toString(InvokerHelper.java:109)
        at groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.getMessage(MissingMethodException.java:55)
```

Not sure why this is happening after restart without any code change.

Comment: Please provide the complete stacktrace

Comment: What is at line 66 of the `cuanto.Project` class?